# Force boolean result from promise function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

In angularjs, I am trying to return get isInternal true or false value based on a promise function. But I am getting another promise (Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state
:
Object
status
:
1
value
:
true)

```js
$scope.isInternal = userInfo.getUser().then(function(user) {return user.internal;});
          console.log($scope.isInternal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try:

```
userInfo.getUser().then(function(user) {
  $scope.isInternal = user.internal;
});
```

Comment: When I try var isInternal = true;
          userInfo.getUser().then(function(user) {
            isInternal = user.internal;
            console.log(isInternal +"--");
          });
          console.log(isInternal+"------");

          Result: false--
true----

Comment: Yes, that's right. The console.log(isInternal+"------"); outside of the promise is executed first, and then it prints true------, then we get the callback from the promise and the then() part of the promise is executed, and it prints the value of user.internal which it seems to be false.

Comment: I need isInternal var value in a different function.

Comment: well you can use it. $scope.isInternal

Answer (score 0):

here is a good tutorial on promises , three is a section there that specificly says why something like this :

var var = service.getAsyncData() ... won't work as expected

[tutorial on promises](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/)